# Python - How to remove some terms of a numpy array in specific intervals

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have the following array:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,
              1,2,3,4,5,
              1,2,3,4,5])
```

How can I manipulate it to remove the term in equally spaced intervals and adapt the new length for it? For example, I'd like to have:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,
     1,2,3,4,
     1,2,3,4]
```

Where the terms from positions 4, 9, and 14 were excluded (so every 5 terms, one gets excluded). If possible, I'd like to have a code that I could use for an array with length N. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you can simply run code below after initializing the `x` array(as you did your question):

```py
x.reshape(3,5)[:,:4]
```

##### Output

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

If you are interested in getting a vector and not a matrix(such as the output above), you can call the `flatten` function on the code above:

```py
x.reshape(3,5)[:,:4].flatten()
```

##### Output

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4,
       1, 2, 3, 4,
       1, 2, 3, 4])
```

##### Explanation

Since `x` is a numpy array, we can use NumPy in-built functions such as `reshape`. This function, which has a self-explanatory name, shapes the array into the desired format. `x` was a vector of 15 elements. Therefore, running `x.reshape(3,5)` gives us a matrix with 3 rows and five columns. `[:, :4]` is to reselect the first four columns. `flatten` function changes a matrix into a vector.

Comment: Thank you @Amirhossein Kiani. Actually it is a vector (note that I used only one [ ]), I just wrote it on several lines to better illustrate the repetition, but maybe wasn't the best idea. Could you please provide more details about the arguments?

Comment: @MateusForcelini Yeah, I am aware that `x` is a vector. And the last output is actually a vector too, I just used brake lines in order to make it more understandable.  I will edit the code in order to make it more clear.

Comment: Thank you again. If possible can you explain to me as well how can I, for instance, exclude the last N elements?

Comment: @MateusForcelini Glad to help, buddy. Excluding the last N elements, not knowing how many elements `x` has, would be erroneous. If you are sure there is a certain number of elements, let's say 15, you can still use `reshape` to make a matrix and delete each column you like. I suggest you take a look at @mozway 's answer as well since his answer would be more fit to what you need.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can use a boolean mask generated with the modulo (%) operator:

```
N = 5
mask = np.arange(len(x))%N != N-1
x[mask]
```

output: `array([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4])`

This works even if your array has not a size that is a multiple of N